# What's the best way to store sorted data with key/value in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new on C# and i'm a little bit lost about all the way to store data with key/
value.

I have a string in key and a int, which is a length in value, and I want to store them and sorted them by the value.

Which way do I need to take ? Dictionary, SortedDictionary, List, KeyValuePair SortedList...

Thank's for your help !

Comment: Dictionary (in the absence of any other requirements), any non trivial c# program is full of them

Comment: As usual it depends upon what how you plan to use it, but SortedDictionary is a good place to start.  Although if you want them sorted by value then you might want to make the value be the key since sorted dictionaries sort by the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most cases, you'd simply use `Dictionary<string, int>`. If you want sorting, you would sort during retrieval, e.g.

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
d.Add("Key2",2);
d.Add("Key1",1);

//Sort by key
foreach (var k1 in d.OrderBy(a => a.Key))
    Console.Writeline(k1.Value);

//Sort by value
foreach (var k2 in d.OrderBy(a => a.Value))
    Console.Writeline(k2.Value);
```

The amount of overhead for the sorting is small enough where most developers won't care.

If you have a very large list and you want more efficient sorting, you can use a `SortedDictionary` instead. There will be slightly more overhead inserting into the dictionary, but retrieval will be more efficient. But a SortedDictionary is sorted by key, not by value, so it probably would not work for your situation.